# Change arrow head in latex style

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, arrows

Yes, I know there is an `arrowhead` option, but for some reason it didn't works. Is there an alternative?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.arrows,arrows.meta}


\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[blue, ultra thick] (0,5) -- (4,5);

\node at (-1, 0) {\huge{$E_0$}};
\node at (-1, 5) {\huge{$E_1$}};

\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3} 
      \draw[red, very thick] (6,\x) -- (10,\x);

\foreach \x in {0,0.2,0.4,0.6} 
      \draw[black, thick] (12,\x) -- (16,\x);

\foreach \x in {1,1.2,1.4,1.6} 
      \draw[black, thick] (12,\x) -- (16,\x);

\foreach \x in {2,2.2,2.4,2.6} 
      \draw[black, thick] (12,\x) -- (16,\x);

\foreach \x in {5,6,7,8} 
      \draw[red, very thick] (6,\x) -- (10,\x);

\foreach \x in {5,5.2,5.4,5.6} 
      \draw[black, thick] (12,\x) -- (16,\x);

\foreach \x in {6,6.2,6.4,6.6} 
      \draw[black, thick] (12,\x) -- (16,\x);

\foreach \x in {7,7.2,7.4,7.6} 
      \draw[black, thick] (12,\x) -- (16,\x);

\draw[latex-latex] (2,0) -- (2,5) node[midway,fill=white]{\huge{$\Delta E_1$}};
               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with arrowhead? They are options with `arrow head` in their name that effect how arrow shapes look like but they don't alter arrow tips.

Comment: In order to draw arrows, you need to add an option such as `<-` or `->` or even `<->` (and you can say `>=latex` or you can directly set `-latex` like you do). But it is totally unclear to me where you want to have arrows in your drawing and how they should look like. So I am unsure how to help here. Note that you load the `arrows` library twice and you additonally load the `arrows.meta` library which provides a much more flexible interface for styling arrow heads. You might want to load only one of these two libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is what you are interested in but you can use **stealth arrows**,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick, {Stealth[length=3mm, width=2.5mm]}-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=8mm]}] (0,-1)--(10,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

giving the following result

[image]

Comment: `tikz` loads `pgf` and for your MWE, only the `arrows.meta` library is really needed.